TypeError: X is not a function (Uncaught (in promise) error)
I'm currently working on this specific issue when using state-changing contract methods using ethers 6.13.2. I've tried searching up similar issues and examples of this error but have not gotten any of the solutions to work. I've provided some example code of the setup and call method.
    const getEthereumContract = async () => {
        const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(ethereum);
        const signer = await provider.getSigner();
        const transactionsContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer);
    
        return transactionsContract;
    }

    const{ addressTo, amount, keyword, message} = formData;
    const transactionsContract = getEthereumContract();
//converts decimal amount
                const parsedAmount = ethers.parseEther(amount);
                await ethereum.request({
                    method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
                    params: [{
                        from: currentAccount,
                        to: addressTo,
                        gas: '0x5208', ////21000
                        value: parsedAmount._hex, ///0.00001
                    }],
                });
                const transactionHash = await transactionsContract.addToBlockchain(addressTo, parsedAmount, message, keyword);

I checked my contract ABI and verified that 'addToBlockchain' method is there with the correctly specified parameters. The metamask transaction is successful but the contract method call is not. Some help would be appreciated, and can provide more context if required.

Can you share your code as a GitHub repo?

Are you able to call that function from Remix ?

@ruby_newbie I have tried that yet, currently working through vsc. I'm trying other solutions in the meantime but if no luck ill give it a shot. I've also tried using read-only type contract methods and get the same issue.

@ruby_newbie after deploying the contract through remix, and debugging my own js code, i found that parseether method is adding an 'n' at the end of the BigInt, which in remix is giving an "Error: invalid BigNumber string". This may potentially be the issue as its trying to get another method with same name but different parameters. Will get back when i have more findings!

Okay, after about a day of debugging, and googling....I found out the issue isn't with the contract being deployed, or passing incorrect parameter types. I was missing 'await' operator when getting an instance of the contract, which is why i kept getting above mentioned error. After adding 'await' to below line of code, the app works as intended. Thanks for the replies above, it ruled out a lot of questions i had when testing them!
const transactionsContract = await getEthereumContract();

